# Why is my python converting my byte array to integers automatically?

Tags: python, arrays, function, file, io

I am writing a program that reads in 16 bytes at a time from 2 files, and has an input byte to compare it to. Now if an occurrence of that byte exists in the 16 bytes of the first file, I want to add the byte in the exact same position in the second file to a list. An issue that I am having is that passing a byte array to another function seems to convert the elements to integers for some reason and I have no idea why?

The code is as follows:
`

```
list = []
def checkoccurence(hexbyte,ciph,block):
    if len(block) > 0:
        block = bytearray(block)
        print(block[0])
    # i = 0
    # while i < len(block):
    #     if int(len(block)) > 0 and int(len(ciph)) > 0:
    #         if ciph[i] == hexbyte:
    #             list.append(block[i])
    #     i += 1
    # return 

def main(): 

    byte = input("Type in the byte to look for as a hex value:")
    file1 = input("File 1")
    file2 = input("File 2")

    readciph = open(file2,'rb') #Open the ciphertext file
 
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f: #Open the plain text file
        stream = []
        while True:
            block = bytearray(f.read(16))
            ciph = readciph.read(16)
            byte = str(byte)
            hexbyte = bytes.fromhex(byte)
            checkoccurence(hexbyte,ciph,block)
            if not block:
                break
        stream += [block]
    print(list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

`

Now if I look at the print statement in the checkoccurence function it just prints the bytes as integers which is giving me a headache as I need to compare the elements as actual bytes. Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?

Tried passing bytes to a function. Expected bytes to be printed. Instead integers were printed.